# Define custom comparator for use with priority_queue

Tags: c++

I want to implement a minHeap in c++ for char[] buffers and am facing some problems with the implementation. My declaration of the priority queue is as follows (I am not sure if this will give me a maxHeap or a minHeap):

```
priority_queue<char[], vector<char[]>, comparePacketContents> receiveBuffer;
```

where `comparePacketContents` is:

```
struct comparePacketContents {
  bool operator()(char lhs[], char rhs[]) const {
    return atoi(TcpPacket::getBytes(lhs, 0, SEQUENCE_SIZE)) < atoi(TcpPacket::getBytes(rhs, 0, SEQUENCE_SIZE));
  }
};
```

and `TcpPacket::getBytes` is:

```
char* TcpPacket::getBytes(char* buf, int start, int size) {
  char* ans = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    *(ans + i) = *(buf + start + i);
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Basically I intend to get the first `SEQUENCE_SIZE` characters of the received packet and then create a heap ordered upon the value of the sequence number.

However, when I try to push a packet into this heap using:

```
receiveBuffer.push(buf);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::priority_queue<_Ty, _Container, _Pr>::push [with _Ty=char [], _Container=std::vector<char [], std::allocator<char []>>, _Pr=comparePacketContents]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (char [2048])
object type is: std::priority_queue<char [], std::vector<char [], std::allocator<char []>>, comparePacketContents>
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: As a side note, your code is rife with memory leaks. I would HIGHLY recommend using `std::string` in place of `char[]`.

Comment: What is the type of `buf` when you call `push()` with it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck `char[2048]`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably "fix" the compilation error by doing `push(&buf)` to push a pointer to the beginning of the array explicitly.  Otherwise the compiler thinks you want to push the entire array, while the container holds pointers (`char[]` is like `char*`).

But probably that's not sufficient to fix all the problems you have, because it seems you are storing raw pointers to C-style strings without managing those allocations correctly.  Instead, consider writing a class to hold your packets:

```
class Packet {
public:
    Packet(const char* data); // takes ownership of data

    uint32_t seqnum() const; // similar to existing implementation
    // ...

private:
    std::shared_ptr<char> m_data;
};

Packet::Packet(const char* data) : m_data(data, free) {
}

bool operator<(const Packet& lhs, const Packet& rhs) {
    return lhs.seqnum() < rhs.seqnum();
}

priority_queue<Packet> receiveBuffer;
```

In my example I assume you release packet buffers using the C `free()` function, but you can use any "deleter" in the C++ `shared_ptr` constructor, including one you write yourself.

Comment: the modification that you suggested doesn't really work out even in terms of compiling properly.. also, I am basically working with network buffers that return c style strings.. what would you suggest i should change (this is my first time working with c strings and I would really appreciate your help in this regard)

Comment: @akhiljain: I have updated my answer with significantly more detail about how you can work with these buffers more cleanly in C++.